# Learn Python the hard way, EX35. Why does a number greater than 10 return true?

Tags: python, logic

So I've just completed Exercise 35 on Learn Python the Hard Way
http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex35.html

The function below is from that exercise. I realize that it's flawed by only checking if "next" is a "0" or a "1" rather than any number (by using .isdigit() or similar), this results in an error for any input greater than 1 but less than 10.

However an input of 10 or greater it seems to work fine. For example if I enter "13" which is obviously not "0" or "1" this statement "if "0" in next or "1" in next:" returns true, how can this be?

def gold_room():
    print "This room is full of gold.  How much do you take?"

```
next = raw_input("> ")
if "0" in next or "1" in next:
    how_much = int(next)
else:
    dead("Man, learn to type a number.")

if how_much < 50:
    print "Nice, you're not greedy, you win!"
    exit(0)
else:
    dead("You greedy bastard!")
```

Comment: Got it, thanks. I thought that it was comparing two strings rather than just looking for the specified character within the string. Each time I tested the code with a number over 9 I must have entered a number with either a 1 or 0 in it and therefore ASSumed all numbers 10 or greater worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing a string comparison. The "1" character is in "13", so this evaluates to TRUE. You seem to be thinking if int(next) == 1, which is a numerical comparison and should behave as you describe.

Answer (score 5):

`raw_input()` returns a string. The expression `'0' in string or '1' in string` does two substring searches. `'1' in '9999'` would evaluate to `False` so numbers >= 10 can fail that test as well.

The exercise is trying to tell you that you need to check the string returned by `raw_input()` is in legal numeric notation and get an `int` value from it with:

```
try:
    how_much = int(next)
except ValueError:
    dead("Man, learn to type a number.")
```

**NOTE**: memorizing what exceptions may be raised by which kind of operations is an important topic when learning Python. Most tutorials don't stress this enough. Beginners would want to memorized that:

- `int('x')` would raise `ValueError`
- `{}['KEY']` would raise `KeyError`
- `[][0]` would raise `IndexError`

when writing any Python code that converts a string to a number, or uses lists or dictionaries.

Comment: I'm not saying it's *bad* to memorize those things, but you only need to know what exact exception class is thrown if you're going to catch it. And if you're going to catch it then you have a test case that will provoke an exception (right?). So you'll find out soon enough what exception is thrown, and you'll remember it once it's happened a few times. You might be able to guess that I'm not a huge fan of up-front rote learning of function interfaces :-)

Comment: @SteveJessop, in _compact_ languages that doesn't have much syntax, where the language ends and the standard library begins can be blurry. Thus to be against all "up-front rote learning of function interfaces" is close to being against "up-front rote learning of programming language keywords".  Surely no reasonable person would argue the latter? ;)

Comment: Heck, in sprawling languages with loads of syntax it's not necessarily any clearer. There isn't really any such formal division in C++, for example. One gets in a mess trying to say that that `typeid` (a keyword) is part of the language whereas `std::type_info` (the type it evaluates to) is not. But sticking to Python, I'm not sure I *would* recommend up-front rote learning for all keywords. `yield` springs to mind as an example that's easier *initially* learned by using it than by memorizing PEP 342 or even just PEP 255. That's best left until later IMO.

Answer (score 1):

`next` is a string which is being treated as a collection of characters. The first character of "13" is "1"; the expression "1" in "13" is true.

Answer (score 1):

I get syntax error on the following code for the gold_room function. Zed challenges us to alter the base code but my attempts to add particular outcomes breaks the program. The problem arises at "if how_much == 68:" ...

```
def gold_room():
    print "This room is full of gold.  How much do you take?"

    choice = raw_input("> ")
    if choice.isdigit():
        how_much = int(choice)
    else:
        dead("Man, learn to type a number. But you can't, because you're dead.")

    if how_much == 68:
        print "Awwwww yea, you crazy."
    elif how_much < 50:
        print "Nice, you're not greedy, you win!"
        exit(0)
    else:
        dead("You greedy bastard!")
```